# How can I get duration of AudioInputStream?

Tags: java, audio, stream, duration

I want to get duraction of an AudioInputStream (in microseconds). How can I easily do that? I found [how can I get duration of an audio file:](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#file_length), but can't do that, because of encapsulation. The only object I see is the instance of an AudioInputStream class.

Comment: ... Microseconds?? Are you sure?

Comment: Milliseconds may be too, but yes, I know what are microseconds;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getFrameLength()` returns the stream length in *frames*, `getFormat().getFrameRate()` will give you the number of *frames per second*.

```
long durationInMillis = 1000 * getFrameLength() / getFormat().getFrameRate();
```